# Swift 4: UIView Subclassing, getting parent view

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm on a practice project, trying to achieve this. 
[image]

Using `UIView Subclassing` I'm almost done with it, I wrote this code with some fellow SF developers.

```
 class Luna: UIView {

     private var screenWidth: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
     }

     override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

     }

     required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

     }

     public func showLuna(inView: UIView, title messageTitle:String, message messageDescription:String, dissmiss dissmissDuration: TimeInterval) {

        let luna = UIView()

        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.text = "Introducing our new football notifications on the Guardian app"
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-demibold", size: 13)
        //titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "4A4A4A")
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0 // whole idea of self-sizing

        let titleDesc = UILabel()
        titleDesc.text = "Today we are excited to announce the launch of our new and improved football notifications in our latest update to the Guardian app."
        titleDesc.font = UIFont(name: "avenirnext-regular", size: 9)
        //titleDesc.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "4A4A4A")
        titleDesc.numberOfLines = 0

        // My mainView

        luna.backgroundColor = .white
        //luna.addShadow(radius: 11, opacity: 0.2) // Some Shadow
        luna.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        let verticalStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, titleDesc])
        verticalStackView.axis = .vertical

        let okButton = UIButton()
        okButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        // okButton.setTitle("Okay", for: .normal)
        okButton.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal) // to stretch the okay button horizontally

        let horizontalStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [verticalStackView, okButton])
        horizontalStackView.axis = .horizontal

        luna.addSubview(horizontalStackView)
        self.addSubview(luna)

        horizontalStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // when using autolayout from code, this property must be false, otherwise constraint won't work
        luna.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            horizontalStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            horizontalStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
            horizontalStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            horizontalStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: luna.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),

            luna.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30),
            luna.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
            luna.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30)
            ]) 

       }
}
```

However, Upon calling `Show Luna` on my other ViewController, The app crashes and gives the following:

> 2018-07-11 10:45:08.999314+0300 LunaView[1344:23604] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to
>   activate constraint with anchors  and  because
>   they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors
>   reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

I'm guessing that the app crashes because of the constraints, given the invalid view to supply. pasting the `Show Luna` code in `ViewDidLoad` of another view controller works, that's if you change the `InView` of constraints to `self.view` like:

[image: SCR1]

But I can't do that through view subclassing. IS that even possible to access the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create constraints between **luna** and **inView** without first inserting luna inside it , so after this line

```
 let luna = UIView()
```

add

```
 inView.addSubview(luna)
```

Comment: Exactly, Thank you so much @Sh_Khan. you've been so helpful lately. god bless you.. Green check mark comes in seconds